# What is Wonderstone and are there any references to it pre-1982?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, magic, content-identification

What is Wonderstone? Is there any source indicating that it was created pre-1982? I'm trying to find a reference to wonderstone in D&D pre-1982.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Could you include any information you already have or what made you wonder (hah) about Wonderstone? Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Can you share why you need this?

Comment: What is “wonderstone”? And what is the significance of 1982?

Comment: This is answerable (wonderstone is a variety of gemstone detailed in Dragon #72 in 1983, a particular variety of real-world mineral rhyolite found in the Forgotten Realms). The asker wants to know if it appears in D&D earlier than this article.

Comment: @QuadraticWizard Questuons need to contain their question though. Perhaps ask the asker if that’s what they’re on about and then edit if it’s confirmed, so it can be voted back open?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The question seems clear to me. What is wonderstone, and do any references to it appear in any D&D source prior to 1982? I'm able to answer this question, and writing an answer as we speak, which is why I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @QuadraticWizard Questions are meant to be clear to everyone reading it. This is lacking context to make it understandable except to 1) people who already know the answer, 2) the asker. Notably missing are the groups of people who 3) need to manage this site, 4) people searching for answers to the same thing but using search terms from the missing context. That’s less than what the point of this site is aiming for. If you understand it, you should use you edit privileges, not just your vote privileges, to improve this resource for the future. We’re not here just to help the one asker.

Comment: A book written in 1982 - The Secret, has the following following reference.   “You’ll see a letter from the country, Of wonderstones hearth”.   There is a picture that goes with the verse that has the “blue glow”.  The purpose is to solve the puzzle to find a real  life “treasure”.  This has not been solved in 37 years.  I recognized wonderstone from Forgotten Realms, but did not know if it was earlier.  I guess it does not help solve the puzzle if it did not come out until 1983 and the book was written and published in 1982.   Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 23):

#### Wonderstone did not appear in D&D until 1983.

[Wonderstone](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Wonderstone) is a [real-world](https://pubs.geoscienceworld.org/sepm/jsedres/article-abstract/86/5/498/145532/the-geologic-context-of-wonderstone-a-complex?redirectedFrom=PDF) semiprecious gemstone referring to a type of banded [rhyolite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyolite). In D&D, wonderstone is noted for its ability to glow blue in the presence of magic.

It first appears in Dungeons & Dragons in the article *Gems Galore* by Ed Greenwood, in Dragon #72 (April 1983), which introduces numerous gemstones which, as the article mentions, are not already listed in the AD&D Dungeon Master's Guide. The AD&D DMG was famous for well-researched and unusually detailed lists based on real-world information, so if even AD&D didn't include such an obscure mineral as wonderstone, it's unlikely that earlier sourcebooks did either.

We can rule out any of the 57 or so pre-1983 TSR publications by a process of elimination. I have, where possible, also personally checked these sourcebooks to confirm.

- We know it's not in the AD&D DMG because the article tells us so. It's not in the PHB since that book didn't detail gems.
- If it's not in extra-detailed AD&D, it's certainly not in any earlier core book or treasure lore book (White Box and Supplements, Holmes/Moldvay Basic, Monster & Treasure Assortment)
- We can assume it's not in any monster, deity of NPC book (AD&D Monster Manual, Fiend Folio, Rogues Gallery, Deities & Demigods).
- Adventure modules of the Original D&D era listed gemstones by value or range of value, not particular names, and on the rare occasion where names are used, it's always a very well-known stone like diamond, not obscure detailed names for ornamental or semiprecious stones (that was introduced by AD&D), and even AD&D didn't have wonderstone in its list. This eliminates about 38 of the 57 or so books in that date range.
- This leaves only the World of Greyhawk Folio (1980), which refers only to gem categories, and refers readers to the Dungeon Master's Guide for further detail.

This only leaves Dragon magazines. Only one earlier article on gemstones appears in [The DragonDex](https://www.aeolia.net/dragondex/articles-subject.html), in Dragon #8. I've checked this article and, while it mentions many gemstones, it does not include wonderstone or rhyolite.

Therefore, it is almost certain wonderstone was first added to D&D by Ed Greenwood in his April 1983 article, and did not canonically acquire its magical properties until much later.

Comment: That's a fine bit of research. +1